# How do I write an Enlive selector to return "clusters" of tags?

Tags: clojure, enlive

I'm writing some Clojure code using Enlive to process a set of XML documents. They're in an XML format that borrows heavily from HTML but adds some custom tags, and my job is to convert them to real HTML. The custom tag that's bothering me the most right now is `<tab>`, which is being used in all kinds of places it shouldn't be. For example, it's often used to make lists which should really have been made with `<ol>` and `<li>`. Here's an example of the kind of thing I'm encountering:

```
<p class="Normal">Some text</p>
<p class="ListWithTabs">(a)<tab />First list item</p>
<p class="ListWithTabs">(b)<tab />Second list item</p>
<p class="ListWithTabs">(c)<tab />Third list item</p>
<p class="Normal">Some more text</p>
<p class="AnotherList">1.<tab />Another list</p>
<p class="AnotherList">2.<tab />Two items this time</p>
<p class="Normal">Some final text</p>
```

I want to turn this into:

```
<p class="Normal">Some text</p>
<ol type="a">
<li class="ListWithTabs">First list item</li>
<li class="ListWithTabs">Second list item</li>
<li class="ListWithTabs">Third list item</li>
</ol>
<p class="Normal">Some more text</p>
<ol type="1">
<li class="AnotherList">Another list</li>
<li class="AnotherList">Two items this time</li>
</ol>
<p class="Normal">Some final text</p>
```

To do this, I need to get the `<p>` elements that contain `<tab>` descendants (easy with Enlive selectors), and somehow cluster them according to the natural groupings they had in the original XML documents (much harder).

I've looked through the documents and determined that I can't rely on the `class` attribute: sometimes these `<p>`-that-should-be-`<li>` elements have the same class as the `<p>` elements around them, and sometimes there are two successive groups of `<p>`-that-should-be-`<li>` elements with the same class as each other (i.e., as if the example I posted had both clusters having the class `ListWithTabs`). The one thing I think I can rely on is that there are never two different lists without at least one non-list element separating them: in other words, any cluster of successive `<p>` elements which all have the property "has at least one `<tab>` element as a descendant" are all part of the same list.

With that in mind, I did some experimenting at the REPL, with Enlive loaded under the namespace `e` (that is, `(require '[net.cgrand.enlive-html :as e])` should be assumed to be in effect for all the rest of my question). It was easy to write a selector to pick out the elements I want, but `(e/select snippet [(e/has [:tab])])` returns a list (well, it's really a lazy sequence) of 5 elements. But what I want is a list of lists: the first with three elements and the second with two. Something vaguely like this (pardon the non-standard indentation):

```
[
  [{:tag :p, :content (... "First list item" ...)}
   {:tag :p, :content (... "Second list item" ...)}
   {:tag :p, :content (... "Third list item" ...)}
  ] ; 3 items in first list
  [{:tag :p, :content (... "Another list" ...)}
   {:tag :p, :content (... "With just two items" ...)}
  ] ; 2 items in second list
]
```

I was able to create the following selectors:

```
(def first-of-tab-group [(e/has [:tab])
                         (e/left (complement (e/has [:tab])))])
(def rest-of-tab-group [(e/has [:tab])
                        (e/left (e/has [:tab]))])
```

But now I'm stuck. I'd like to do something like `(e/select snippet [[(e/start-at first-of-tab-group) (e/take-while rest-of-tab-group)]])`, but as far as I know Enlive doesn't have any functions like `start-at` and `take-while`.

It feels like I'm very close, but just missing one final key step. So how do I take the last step? How do I select just a "cluster" of elements that match certain rules, but omit other elements that would match the same rules but aren't part of that first "cluster"?

Comment: Answering my own question... maybe. It looks like fragments (`{from-selector to-selector}`) are what I want. Don't know how I missed that first time around.

Comment: Could you actually answer it if so?

Answer (score 0):

According to enlive documentation: {node-selector node-selector} we can group those with
{[:p.Normal] [:p.Normal]} assuming that  is the delimiter.

Now, my question is: How do one iterates over the results inside each resulting group with enlive.